# How can I improve this query?

Tags: ms-access

I have the following query that (in my opinion) is far too long than it needs to be and contains statements which can be merged. The trouble is, I don't know how to do it :)

Is there any way I can improve on this to make it 'better'?

```
SELECT `Date`, `Time`, 

    (SELECT `Buyer Name` 
     FROM [Potential Buyer]
     WHERE `Buyer No` = [Viewing Appointment].`Buyer No`) AS 'Buyer Name',

     (SELECT `Name`
      FROM [Seller] 
      WHERE `Seller No` = (SELECT `Seller No`
                           FROM [Sale Property]
                           WHERE `Property Code` = [Viewing Appointment].`Property Code`)) AS 'Seller Name',

     (SELECT `Address` 
      FROM [Sale Property]
      WHERE `Property Code` = [Viewing Appointment].`Property Code`) AS 'Property Address',

      (SELECT `Name`
       FROM [Staff Member]
       WHERE `Staff ID` = [Viewing Appointment].`Staff Appointed`) AS 'Staff Members Name'

FROM [Viewing Appointment]
```

Also, currently the order of the fields being selected is Date, Time, Buyer Name, Seller Name, Property Address, Staff Members Name. Is there anyway I can change the order of this?

Thanks.

Comment: I am unclear on why you want your question deleted.  It appears from the edit history that you are irritated by other people editing your question.  That's how it works here.  Like Wikipedia, this site is collaboratively edited, and all edits are tracked. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your questions and answers being edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

Comment: Also, when you post a question, you license it to the community so, unless there's a compelling reason, it's not really kosher to delete it.  See http://stackoverflow.com/faq for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, look at joins

Restructure your SQL as follows:

```
SELECT 
[Viewing Appointment].`Date`, 
[Viewing Appointment].`Time`, 
[Potential Buyer].`Buyer Name`,
Seller.Name,
[Sale Property].Address,
[Staff Member].Name

FROM [Viewing Appointment]

LEFT JOIN [Potential Buyer] ON [Potential Buyer].`Buyer No` = [Viewing Appointment].`Buyer No`
LEFT JOIN [Sale Property].`Property Code` = [Viewing Appointment].`Property Code`
LEFT JOIN Seller ON Seller.`Seller No` = [Sale Property].`Seller No`
LEFT JOIN [Staff Member] ON [Staff Member].`Staff ID` = [Viewing Appointment].`Staff Appointed`
```

You can change the order of the fields just by selecting them in a different order